# Cuboid diagonals

Tags: geometry, vectors

The points $M$ and $N$ are taken to be on the diagonals $AB_1$ and $BC_1$ of the cuboid $ABCD-A_1B_1C_1D_1$. If $MN \parallel A_1C$ , find the $MN:A_1C$ ratio.
Initially I understood what's going on here, but unfortunately I can't solve it... The problem requires vector solution. I have no idea how to do it. Can anyone solve it then explain beautifully?? I will glad...

[image]

Comment: Try assigning coordinates $A(0,0,0), D(L,0,0), A_1(0,0,H),B(0,H,0)$ etc.  Try to solve it that way, then translate to vectors.

Answer (score 1):

You may assume that the big box is the unit cube $[0,1]^3$. You then have
$M=(0,\mu,\mu)$,$\>N=(\nu,1,\nu)$. You now have to determine $\mu$ and  $\nu$, such that the vector $\vec{MN}=(\nu,1-\mu,\nu-\mu)$ is parallel to $\vec{A_1C}=(1,1,-1)$. This fortunately has a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the hints. Proceed along these lines and in case of doubts, show your work first.

- In a $3$-d coordinate system, set $A=(0,0,0)$, $C=(L,W,0)$, $A_1=(0,0,H)$
- Using similarity, find coordinates of $M=(0,y,\frac{H}{W}y)$ and $N=(x,W,\frac{H}{L}x)$
- The unit vector parallel to $AC$ or $MN$ is $\frac{1}{|A_1C|}(L,W,-H)$. Hence position vectors $M,N$ satisfy
  $$N=M+\frac{|MN|}{|A_1C|}(L,W,-H)$$

On equating the components, a numerical value of $MN:A_1C$ is obtained.

> $$\frac{MN}{A_1C}=\frac{1}{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

If $MN \, || \, A_1C$ then the lines $A_1C$ and $MN$ lie on a common plane $p$, i.e. the points $\, A_1, \, C,\, M, \, N \, \in \, p $. Let $p$ intersect $BB_1$ in point $L$. Since the points $A, M, L$ lie on both planes $p$ and plane $ABB_1A_1$, the lie on the intersection of these two planes. However, in 3D, two non-overlapping intersecting planes can only intersect in a common line, so $A, M, L$ are colinear, i.e. $L \in AM$. Analogously, $L \in CN$. Thus, one can look at the triangle $\Delta \, ACL$ and see that the segment $MN$ in this triangle is parallel to the side $AC$. By Thales' intercept theorem,
$$\frac{LM}{MA_1} = \frac{LN}{NC}$$
But now let's look at the rectangle (parallelogram is enough) $ABB_1A_1$ with the two lines $AB_1$ and $LA_1$ intersecting at point $M$. Since $AA_1 \, || \, BB_1$ again by Thales' intercept theorem
$$\frac{LM}{MA_1} = \frac{LB_1}{AA_1}$$
Analogously, if you look at the rectangle (parallelogram is enough) $BB_1C_1C$ with the two lines $BC_1$ and $LC$ intersecting at point $N$, then since $BB_1 \, || \, CC_1$ again by Thales' intercept theorem
$$\frac{LN}{NC} = \frac{LB}{CC_1}$$
If you look at the ratios we have written so far, they are all equal, so you get
$$\frac{LB_1}{AA_1} =  \frac{LM}{MA_1} = \frac{LN}{NC} = \frac{LB}{CC_1}$$ which means that
$$\frac{LB_1}{AA_1} = \frac{LB}{CC_1}$$ and since $AA_1 = BB_1$ you finally get
$$LB_1 = LB$$ i.e. $L$ is the midpoint of the edge $BB_1$. Thus, if you go back to
$ABB_1C_1$ with its two lines $AB_1$ and $LA_1$, which intersect at $M$, Thales' theorem gives you
$$\frac{LM}{MA_1} = \frac{LB_1}{AA_1} = \frac{LB_1}{BB_1} \,\,\, \text{ because } \,\, AA_1 = BB_1$$ so
$$\frac{LM}{MA_1} = \frac{LB_1}{BB_1} = \frac{1}{2}$$
Returning back to $\Delta \, ACL$ and the fact that $MN \, || \, A_1C$, Thales' therorem yields
$$\frac{MN}{A_1C} = \frac{LM}{LA_1} = \frac{LM}{LM + MA_1} =?$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $$\vec{AA_1}=\mathbf{a},\\
\vec{AB}=\mathbf{b},\\
\vec{AD}=\mathbf{d},\\
\frac{MA}{B_1A}=\lambda,\\
\frac{BN}{BC_1}=\mu,$$
and, since $MN\parallel A_1C,$ $$\vec{MN}=k\,\vec{A_1C}.$$

Now, $$\vec{MN}=\vec{MA}+\vec{AB}+\vec{BN}$$

> $$k\,\vec{A_1C}=\lambda\,\vec{B_1A}+\mathbf{b}+\mu\,\vec{BC_1}\\ k(-\mathbf{a}+\mathbf{b}+\mathbf{d})=\lambda(-\mathbf{b}-\mathbf{a})+\mathbf{b}+\mu(\mathbf{d}+\mathbf{a})\\ (-k+\lambda-\mu)\mathbf{a}+(k+\lambda-1)\mathbf{b}+(k-\mu)\mathbf{d}=\mathbf{0}.$$

Since $\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b}$ and $\mathbf{d}$ are not coplanar (i.e., they are linearly independent), their coefficients are all $0.$

> Therefore, $$k=\frac13 \\ \vec{MN}=\frac13\vec{A_1C} \\ MN:A_1C=1:3.$$